# `git stash --patch` showing lines changed that `git diff`/`git status` are not showing

Tags: git, msysgit

When I try to do `git stash save --patch` I get a lot patch changes that aren't visible in `git diff` or `git status`. Each change removes some lines and then reinserts the same lines, without apparent change, e.g.:

```
-Some text line
+Some text line
-Another line
+Another line
```

All these changes are in a resource file that hasn't been touched in a while. My platform is Windows using Git for Windows.

Why is `git stash` showing me different things than `git diff` and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has something to do with the infamous git line endings / `core.autocrlf` options and the `.gitattributes` file. Even though I do not understand the cause, I have found the solution for my case.

It turns out that some git process¹ had created an untracked `.gitattributes` file in my local repository. Almost all of the lines in this file were commented out, except for near the top it has:

```
* text=auto
```

When I comment out this line, as such

```
#* text=auto
```

the problems with `git stash` go away and I see only the changes that `git diff` sees.

---

¹) I suspect the cause was a new Visual Studio C# project I created in the same repository -- I'm guessing the IDE detected the repository and added the file.